# await operator giving issue when using with lambda

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have 2 Entity and I want to copy some data from Second Entity to First Entity and after that I want to return a simple string saying Success.I am using Polly to make http request.I am planning to get data in json and then convert it in my Entity model and do the manipulation which I am able to do but Calling both the task which return differnt types(can be slight different data model) giving some error.I am not so good in Multithreading approach.

```
public interface IMyRepository 
{
    string ValidateData(MyData myData);
}


public class MyRepository :IMyRepository 
{        private  readonly RetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _httpRequestPolicy;

    public MyRepository()
    {

        _httpRequestPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(
             r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
         .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
             retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt), (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context1) =>
             {
                 var msg = $"Retry {retryCount} implemented with Pollys RetryPolicy " +
                 $"of {context1.PolicyKey} " +
                 $"at {context1.ExecutionKey}, " +
                 $"due to: {exception}.";


             });
    }

    public  string  ValidateData(MyData MyData)
    {            
       var MyDataOne= Task<MyData>.Factory.StartNew(() => await  MyRepository.getProfileOne());
       var MyDataTwo= Task<MyData>.Factory.StartNew(() => await  MyRepository.getProfileTwo());
       //Update some property of MyDataOne on basis of MyDataTwo and return true or fasle in variable **result**
        return result;
    }

    public static async Task<InsuranceCompanyData> getCusomerProfile()
    {
        var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
        string requestEndpoint = "numbers/Get";

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _httpRequestPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestEndpoint));

        IEnumerable<int> numbers = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<int>>();
        return  new InsuranceCompanyData();
    }
    private  static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:2351/api/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return httpClient;
    }
}

public static async  Task<MyData> getProfileOne()
{
    var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
    string requestEndpoint = "/numbers/Get1";

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _httpRequestPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestEndpoint));

   // IEnumerable<string> data1= await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();
    return  new MyData();
}

public static async  Task<MyData> getProfileTwo()
{
    var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
    string requestEndpoint = "/numbers/Get2";

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await _httpRequestPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestEndpoint));

  //  IEnumerable<string> data2= await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();
    return  new MyyData();
}

private  static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:2351/api/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return httpClient;
}
```

I get these errors:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.

And

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyRepository._httpRequestPolicy'

Comment: Why are you calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` at all? Just call both methods and remember the tasks they return, then await both tasks.

Comment: I want those to be independent and asynchronous so I was calling Task.Factory.StartNew.Sorry but I did not understood your suggestion.If I do not write `Task.Factory.StartNew` and write  `var InsuranceCompanyData=  await  InsuranceCompanyRepository.getCusomerProfile();` I get "
`Error CS4032 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<string>'.`

Comment: You're trying to mix sync and async here, just stick with one and you won't see these problems.

Comment: If they're properly asynchronous methods, you shouldn't need to explicitly start new tasks. If they're *not* properly asynchronous, I'd look at making them asynchronous instead.

Comment: @DaisyShipton-I do not understand that methods are not asynchronous.Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Task.Factory.StartNew` which is not recommended and doesn't support async lambdas (which you don't even need here), use `Task.Run`:

```
var profileOneTask = Task.Run(() => getProfileOne());
var profileTwoTask = Task.Run(() => getProfileTwo());
```

Notice that I changed the variable names to reflect what they actually are. They are tasks that may, at some point, have a result. They are not the result of those operations.

For the second problem, you declared `_httpRequestPolicy` as an instance member when you should have declared it as a static member for it to be usable without an instance. As discussed in the comments, though, you could just make `getProfileOne` and `getProfileTwo` instance methods.

Comment: I can not make it `_httpRequestPolicy` static  as I need to initialize it in constructor  ` _httpRequestPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(
                 r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)`

Comment: Any way,I will make the changes as sugested by you.Thanks   a lot.

Comment: @PoojaMalik If you can edit your question and add the code that gives you that problem, I'll update my answer to show how you can modify it

Comment: @PoojaMalik I see, but unless you need a new instance of `_httpRequestPolicy` for every instance of `MyRepository`, you could just make it static and assign it inline

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I could not understand.I need polly for every instance so it can retry for every instance and make sure it is resilient.Appologies if I could not understand properly.Also,assign it inline(do you mean static constructor)

Comment: @PoojaMalik You are welcome. I have updated my answer to reflect what I meant

Comment: Thanks but this way,I need to write same code for all solutions i.e.(5) .Also,makingit static will restrict any other feature of polly which I want to implement using existing instance .For eg-I can not use Custome logging and other feature.

Comment: Then remove the `static` modifier from `getProfileOne` and `getProfileTwo`. That seems like the easiest option

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't change `ValidateData` signature and add `async` keyword to method ?

```
    public async Task<string> ValidateDataAsync(MyData MyData)
    {            
       var task1 = Task<MyData>.Factory.StartNew(() => MyRepository.getProfileOne());
       var task2 = Task<MyData>.Factory.StartNew(() => MyRepository.getProfileTwo());

       await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)       

       //Update some property of MyDataOne on basis of MyDataTwo and return true or fasle in variable **result**
        return result;
    }
```

As @Camilo Terevinto said it's better to use `Task.Run` instead of `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

[Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Comment: Thanks but I can not change` ValidateData` because I do not want to change an existing Interface

Comment: you can change it to `Task.WhenAll().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` without `await`